# can I use hiddenservice address for irc and ssh or just one

Tags: onion-routing

> I was wondering If i can use extra onion address I got from code as >showing:
>
> Step Three: More advanced tips
>
> If you plan to keep your service available for a long time, you >might want to make a backup copy of the private_key file somewhere.
>
> If you want to forward multiple virtual ports for a single hidden >service, just add more HiddenServicePort lines. If you want to run >multiple hidden services from the same Tor client, just add another >HiddenServiceDir line. All the following HiddenServicePort lines >refer to this HiddenServiceDir line, until you add another >HiddenServiceDir line:

```
HiddenServiceDir /usr/local/etc/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080

HiddenServiceDir /usr/local/etc/tor/other_hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 6667 127.0.0.1:6667
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

> I use that in torrc and I restart tor browser and now I got two >onion address one onion address is for my website and other one can >be use for irc and ssh or just only irc and if so where I can learn >how to make my own onion irc or ssh. I would ratter have both if >not I would like use irc. I look everywhere on the net for this and >I can't never find anything about this topic on how to set it up. I >was wondering if someone can point me in right direction if so that >would be awesome and thank you for your time...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's like an old-good STunnel: you can make as many port forwardings as you wish. After `HiddenServiceDir` line you just put - one line per port - as many `HiddenServicePort` forwards as you wish, **just make sure there're no empty lines**. And for one onion-name you can use irc, ssh, http, https and whatever you wish at the same time, there's no limits for the number of forward rules.

UPDATE: How to utilize the services

- **OpenSSH** - the simpliest one. It's by default listens on everywhere, including 127.0.0.1, so **just** adding a forward line like `HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22` **does the whole trick**, no further Tor HS configuration is needed! If you've bound the server to the list of IP's in your `sshd_config` - just make sure it listens on 127.0.0.1:22 as well
- **IRC** - so, if you do want to have onion-only server, just put it to listen on 127.0.0.1:6667, if you're about to make an onion entrance to existing server - **there can be a problem**, but it's not difficult to solve. Here is the checklist for IRC:

  1. There're some rare servers, not just IRC, that can open only one single socket by some odd reasons, and it can be listening on X.Y.Z.V:6667 - so `HiddenServicePort 6667 127.0.0.1:6667` turns into `HiddenServicePort 6667 X.Y.Z.V:6667`
  2. If a separate socket for 127.0.0.1:6667 can be raised - good, a line `HiddenServicePort 6667 127.0.0.1:6667` stays as it is, but you'll probably need to revert to pt.1 solution - depends on server+IRCServices because of pt.3
  3. **READ AND CHECK IN FULL AND CAREFULLY!** Landmine lies here. The historically IRC have had IDENT checks, which are requiring **reverse** connection from server to client, most of IRC clients like mIRC and xIRC even has the "ident port" setting in a connection creation window. So - you need to disable IDENT, reverse-DNS and blacklist-lookup for 127.0.0.1 **client source address** if your IRC server and services do allow a selective disabling, or disable them at all. You'll ask - where is the trick? The answer is short - you will pass ANY connection test to onion IRC, *including via client*, because these checks are dropping clients not instantly, but in 20-60 seconds, if enabled - it's tuneable in the IRC server or services parameters or config files. So you'll get a *practically unuseable* service that passes all the "connection tests" - if you'll step on this landmine

That's it! Happy working! Have a nice ride - and feel free to ask the questions, I'm glad to help! Cheers!

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with having empty lines. I've no idea why you've stated this or made it bold.

Comment: as the documentation states - yes, the order is important, not empty lines, but for beginners - empty lines are good "compartment" separators for a config file, and it's a way harder to put a line in a wrong place.

Comment: The user asks a beginner's question, so - yes, I give him a very handy hint not to mess things up. I didn't said that adding the empty line breaks anything, don't distort my words

Comment: I got the address from using that in torrc file and what not but I have no idea how to make it active and there isn't much on it because I want it to be irc onion same as ssh just like how I got my onion site active by using  httpd-vhosts with my onion site and it's up and running. The question I have is How can I turn my irc/ssh into onion use much like my site is. If that don't make sense I can explain it much more clear for ya. Thank you for your time...